# Better way to get json data from relational databases?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, wcf, serialization

I don't know my title is understandable but actually I want to know which one is better?

1-Creating object class and get data from mssql db with loop

2-Getting data from sql db with json format

3-Something else..

I think, loop can be slow when working with big datas. However maybe using **json path** can be slower than loop.

Example for 1 (*CREATING OBJECT IN LOOP*)

```
List<objExample > retVal = new List<objExample >();
objExample item;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
SqlDataAdapter da;
SqlCommandcmd;
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select a,b from table", con);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
foreach (DataRow itemdr in dt.Rows)
{
item = new objExample();
item.A= itemdr["a"].ToString();
item.B= itemdr["b"].ToString();
item.HasError = false;
retVal.Add(item);
}
return retVal;
```

Example for 2 (*FOR JSON PATH*)

```
List<objExample > retVal;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING");
SqlDataAdapter da;
SqlCommandcmd;
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select a,b from table for json path", con);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
string _json = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
retVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<objExample>>(_json);
return retVal;
```

I tried both of them with small data but it didn't satisfy me.

PS : I wrote codes in my mind. Sorry about wrong codes and bad English.

Please guide to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, are you reading the complete table?

If the goal is to get data that is stored within the json, and maybe perform some queries on it a NoSQL DB seems more appropriate that a SQL one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but we have to use mssql unfortunately. And sometimes I am reading all the table.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of commands that are dependent on the number of rows. Kind of how we do the Big O Complexity. 
I would do something like:

```
  using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select a,b from table for json path", con))
{
   try
     {
       using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
             item = new objExample();
             item.A= reader["a"].ToString();
             item.B= reader["b"].ToString();
             item.HasError = false;
             retVal.Add(item);

            }
           }

      }
```

}

Keep in mind that the sql connection will remain open while you are doing this so its judgement call if you want to do this after loop or in the loop.
And the da.Fill or using the above is same internally, still going to iterate over all rows.
As far as using json is concerned, I wouldn't do that unless you are asking if storing as Json file is a better option than in sql. That's a whole diff question.

You can use PLINQ to process the data in parallel once you have it in the list, even for your above deserialization you can try PLINQ.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and advice but I have a question. "for json path" is necessary in your code?

Comment: @EnderKaya yes. It’s a sql keyword.